# Reading Data from API response

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get specific data from a website API.

This is what I have, which just dumps the entire response into google sheets then I use mid to pull the correct string.

Is there a way to just return the value of "unpaid"?

Here is the response I get:

```
{"status":"OK","data":{"time":1612834200,"lastSeen":1612834035,"reportedHashrate":154783794,"currentHashrate":131055555.55555557,"validShares":116,"invalidShares":0,"staleShares":3,"averageHashrate":150218750,"activeWorkers":3,"unpaid":26075516667066776,"unconfirmed":null,"coinsPerMin":0.00000787562193181224,"usdPerMin":0.013755797534761213,"btcPerMin":2.9738348414523017e-7}}
```

All I want out of it is

```
"unpaid":26075516667066776
```

Below is the script I'm using to pull that data into google sheets.

```
function callNumbers() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  
  var data = response.getContentText();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(49,7).setValue([data]);

}
```

I can't seem to find much information on this, or I just don't know where to look. I got the above functions from a google page and then adapted them to pull the information from the website address that I wanted.

Thanks

Comment: Advertising "You're new" doesn't add anything to the question and only distracts from the problem. If you're learning that's great, but that's a given, as on the whole we are all "new" when it comes to things we don't yet understand.

Comment: Where does `fetch()` come from? Is it an async function or does it require a callback?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to show what the returned payload looks like. Also please show what you've tried, regarding parsing the content, and what specific issue you're running into.

Comment: Please explain what "Is the a way to just return the value of "unpaid"?" this means?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Instead of sending the `data` for `setValue()`, try sending `data.unpaid` to the sheet. But I think, in that case, you need to change the `getRange()` params as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that i had to change a few things. This what i ended up with.

```
function callNumbers() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL");
  var var2 = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(49,7).setValue([var2.data.unpaid]);
  Logger.log(var2.data.unpaid);
}
```